# Autoincrement class for field collection items in template

Tags: entities

I have a field collection, which contains another field collection and a field.

Right now I'm using a `.tpl` file to theme this collection and I'm wrapping content inside a div.

I want every item to have an auto-increment ID. For example: row-1, row-2, row-3 etc.

I've tried `for`, `foreach` and the [serial module](https://www.drupal.org/project/serial) and nothing works.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: You mention multiple levels of field collections and another field. Which field are you themeing with the tpl? What element do you want to add the row ID to? What code did you try for the for and foreach loops?

Comment: Your TPL file should already contain a loop over all values, right? So what's the problem with adding `count++` to that loop? Post the code you are talking about, plz. Because as far as I know what you say is about right...